# Run ActiveX control in command line?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I'm writing a web crawler. Unfortunately, the site to be crawled is very old, and it uses some ActiveX controls.

I want my crawler to run in command line, or at least not to load the whole Internet Explorer. Is it even possible to run an ActiveX control in command line?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to develop an ActiveX Exe instead so you can run it over the command line and add some switches:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262306(v=vs.60).aspx